# "Reverse" Vieta's Formulas

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials

In one of my investigations, I needed to figure out sums of powers of roots of polynomial equations. These are not very hard to figure out. For monic polynomials, the first three sums are:

```
Sum of roots: -a_{n-1}
Sum of squares: a_{n-1}²-2a_{n-2}
Sum of cubes: -a_{n-1}³+3a_{n-1}a_{n-2}-3a_{n-3}
```

Would anyone have a reference where all of these formulas can be found? Do you know of any applications that these formulas have?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials

Comment: I think you'll find what you need in [this](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Sum%20of%20Powers%20of%20Roots.pdf)